# How does const modifier for member functions affect overload resolution?

Tags: c++, c++11, overloading, function-qualifier

I have the following test code:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class CString
{
public:
    CString(char const*) {}
};

class TestBed
{
public:
    void Comparison(CString const&) { std::cout << "CString Overload" << std::endl; }
    void Comparison(std::string const&) { std::cout << "std::string overload" << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
    TestBed tb;
    tb.Comparison("Hello World");
}
```

This code fails to compile because the call to `Comparison()` is ambiguous. I expect this behavior.

However, when I make either of the `Comparison()` overloads `const`, as in: `void Comparison(std::string const&) const` or `void Comparison(CString const&) const` (but not both), the code compiles and chooses the non-const overload.

Overload resolution rules are pretty complex and I haven't seen anything that describes how `const` affects this situation. My understanding is:

1. Function with exact matching argument is chosen first
2. 1-level implicit conversion is tried next

In both cases, 1 & 2 are ambiguous. Can someone explain this? Thanks.

Comment: The `this` pointer is also a (hidden) parameter, and enters into the resolution. The prototype with the fewest implicit conversions wins, where non-const to const is a conversion.

Comment: @Creris the const version of the function requires 2 conversions (one for the string and one for `this`), the non-const only 1.

Comment: @MarkRansom no sorry, I thought he added new overload, and in fact he edits one of them, so it goes 1, 1 conversions -> 2, 1 conversions.

Comment: The const version implies two conversions: string literal -> string object, and `TestBed&` -> `const TestBed&` (for `*this`). The non-const version only has the first conversion (string), but not the second one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For class methods, the `this` part is considered as if it were an extra argument. So if you made the `CString` one const, that makes the overload set:

```
Comparison(const TestBed&, CString const&) // (1)
Comparison(TestBed&, std::string const&)   // (2)
```

For `(1)`, we need to do two conversions: a `const` conversion, and a conversion to `CString`. But for `(2)`, we only need to do a single conversion: to `std::string`. Thus, `(2)` is preferred.

We can verify this by adding a third function that does one single conversion for `this`:

```
Comparison(const TestBed&, const char*)  // (3)
```

Here, we again only have a single conversion (in the "first" argument), and thus the overload set is ambiguous.

---

In [over.match.funcs]:

> a member function is considered to have an extra parameter, called the implicit object parameter, which
>   represents the object for which the member function has been called. For the purposes of overload resolution, both static and non-static member functions have an implicit object parameter, but constructors do not.
>
> For non-static member functions, the type of the implicit object parameter is
>
> — “lvalue reference to cv X” for functions declared without a ref-qualifier or with the & ref-qualifier
>
> — “rvalue reference to cv X” for functions declared with the && ref-qualifier
>
> where X is the class of which the function is a member and cv is the cv-qualification on the member
>   function declaration. [ Example: for a const member function of class X, the extra parameter is assumed to
>   have type “reference to const X”. —end example ]
>
> During overload resolution, the implied object argument is indistinguishable from other arguments.

That establishes why we consider `const TestBed&` vs `TestBed&`. And then it's just a matter of comparison the conversion sequences between the overloads `(1)` and `(2)`. For the 2nd argument, both conversion sequences are equal, but for the 1st argument, `(2)` has a better conversion sequence (namely Exact) - which is why it wins without ambiguity.

Comment: I was tempted to expand my comment into a full answer as you did, but I figured a good answer would need some reference to the standard.

Comment: @MarkRansom Tried. It's hard to get a small section from Overload Resolution to fit in an answer.

Comment: Good job. I never though about the fact that `static` functions also need to refer to the constness of the object, even though `this` isn't a parameter anymore.

Comment: Binding to either `const TestBed&` or `TestBed&` has exact match rank. Neither involves a conversion. Instead, the tiebreaker in [over.ics.rank]/p3, bullet 3.1.6 is what makes the `TestBed&` one better.

Comment: @MarkRansom Why do static methods need to check constness? They can't be overloaded via const AFAIK, so I don't see the point.

Comment: @void.pointer you're right, I was a bit confused. Of course constness only applies to the non-static members of a class.